# Is it possible to create your own columns in the TYPO3 back-end

Tags: typo3, fluid, typo3-6.2.x

In TYPO3 CMS we have left, normal, right and border columns as default. Is it possible to create your own columns in the BE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please go to listview and click new element

there should be backend layout available

put in konfiguration something like

```
backend_layout {
  colCount = 3
  rowCount = 3
  rows {
        1 {
            columns {
                1 {
                   name = oben
                   colPos = 10
                   colspan = 3
                }
            }
        }
        2 {
            columns {
                1 {
                   name = linke Spalte
                   colPos = 0
                }
                2 {
                   name = mittlere Spalte
                   colPos = 1
                }
                3 {
                   name = rechte Spalte
                   colPos = 2
                }
            }
        }
        3 {
            columns {
                1 {
                   name = unten
                   colPos = 11
                   colspan = 3
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

i think this is a good example how you can make usage of rows and cols

then go to a page where you want to use this layout go to page --> edit and choose the layout

you see in my example that i have colPos = 11 for example

to get the content from colPos = 11 you need to tell your template that

index.html:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="col9 last contentInner">
        <f:cObject typoscriptObjectPath="lib.title" />
        <f:format.raw>{normaleseitecolpos0}</f:format.raw>
    </div>
</div>
```

this is your fluidtemplate

first `<f:cObject ....` links to a lib that you can use in setup.ts

second `<f:format.raw....` links to a colpos related variable

if you add this to the setup.ts

```
page {
    10 = FLUIDTEMPLATE
    10 {
        file = fileadmin/templates/knowhow/layout/index.html
                variables {
            # Einspalter
            normaleseitecolpos0 < styles.content.get
            normaleseitecolpos0.select.where = colPos = 11
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: there is a nice wizard to create the config. also, in PAGE, you can select different templates with a CASE, let me know if you need it

Comment: @Urs Well, feel free to add your own answer or submit a link to a blog post. We need more English content for TYPO3. :)